# How to access the dynamically generated tuple in Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have created a tuple for django model choices dynamically. The choices look like this 
`[('cash', 'Pay via cash'), ('internet_banking', 'Pay via internet banking'), ('C2P', 'Pay via Credit Card')]`
Created it dynamically because the generated options depend on some conditions. Number and Type of available payment options depend on certain conditions.

Now, I want to access this dynamically generated choices throughout the code, like if selected choices is `cash`, then do this, otherwise do something else.

Unable to use something like this 
`PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES.cash` get error 
`Tuple object has no attribute cash`

Comment: It looks like you added the tuples to a list. You would have to iterate over it, like `for payment_option in mylist: if payment_option[0] == "cash": #do stuff`

Comment: @tst seems ok, but not in my case. It does not matter to me whether payment_option[0] is cash or not. I want to test whether selected method is cash or not. I do have access to the selected method (self.payment_method), would like to use something like ```if self.payment_method == PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES.cash```

Comment: What about converting PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES to a dict: ```self.payment_method == dict(PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICESS)['cash']```

Comment: @S.K I understand that. "cash" in my example can be a variable with the actual user input. Maybe share some code - I am not sure I understand what data you are working with and what data types they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can access tuple elements by their index. If you want to access members like `PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES.cash`, you should create an Enum as below:

```
from enum import Enum

class PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES(Enum):

    cash = 'Pay via cash'
    internet_banking = 'Pay via internet banking'
    C2P = 'Pay via Credit Card'
```

With this Enum, you can check as...

```
if self.payment_method == PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES.cash.value:
```